# C, number defined as int, double in function

Tags: c

```
Input.txt : 
1. M 17 160 13.24
2. M 18 177 13.22
3. M 15 162 14.78
4. F 16 169 15.55
5. F 16 161 14.73
6. F 16 160 10.80
7. M 14 192 15.65
8. F 18 197 12.41
```

I am now having trouble with the function

(this function was given by the teacher)

```
void calculateAverages(double *dAvHeight, double *dAvAge, double *dAvTime, Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);
```

I can only define `dAvHeight dAvAge dAvTime` as Ints, however later on i need to change them to float to calculate averages. Can anyone explain how i do that while keep using `dAvHeight dAvAge dAvTime`.

My question is why can i only define the averages as int if in the function it says double? does the function change the format?

Thanks again

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int iNumberOfLines = 1;
int dAvHeight = 0, dAvAge = 0, dAvTime = 0;




typedef struct {
int ignore;
char Gender;
int Age;
int Height;
float Time;
} Student_t;



int determineNumberOfLines(FILE *pInputFile);
void readInputData(FILE *pInputFile,  int iNumberOfLines, Student_t *pStudents);
void calculateAverages(double *dAvHeight, double *dAvAge, double *dAvTime, Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);
// Student_t* searchFastest(Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);

// void printToConsole(Student_t *pFastestStudent, double dAvHeight, double dAvAge, double dAvTime);



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    FILE *pInputFile = fopen ("resources/Input.txt", "r");
    if (pInputFile == NULL){
            printf("Fehler beim Öffnen");
            return -1;
        }
    determineNumberOfLines(pInputFile);
    //printf("LINES: %d\n",determineNumberOfLines(pInputFile));
    Student_t pStudents[iNumberOfLines];
    //printf("%d", iNumberOfLines);
    readInputData(pInputFile, iNumberOfLines, pStudents);

    calculateAverages(dAvHeight, dAvAge, dAvTime, pStudents, iNumberOfLines);

    return 0;

}

int determineNumberOfLines(FILE *pInputFile){

fopen ("resources/Input.txt", "r");
    int ch;
    while(!feof(pInputFile))
    {
      ch = fgetc(pInputFile);
      if(ch == '\n')
      {
          iNumberOfLines++;
      }
    }

    fclose(pInputFile);
    return iNumberOfLines;

}

void readInputData(FILE *pInputFile, int iNumberOfLines, Student_t *pStudents){

fopen ("resources/Input.txt", "r");

int i = 0;
char buffer [120];



while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pInputFile) != 0)
{

 if (sscanf(buffer, "%d. %c %d %d %f", &pStudents[i].ignore, &pStudents[i].Gender, &pStudents[i].Age, &pStudents[i].Height, &pStudents[i].Time) <= sizeof buffer)
        {
             i++;
        }

}
fclose(pInputFile);
}

void calculateAverages(double *dAvHeight, double *dAvAge, double *dAvTime, Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines){
    int i;
    int sumHeight = 0;
    int sumAge = 0;
    float sumTime = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= (iNumberOfLines-1); i++){
        sumHeight = sumHeight + pStudents[i].Height;
    }
    dAvHeight = sumHeight/ iNumberOfLines;
    printf("Average Height is = %.2f \n", dAvHeight);


    for (i = 0; i<= (iNumberOfLines-1); i++){
        sumAge = sumAge + pStudents[i].Age;
    }
    //dAvAge = sumAge/iNumberOfLines;
    printf("Average Age is = %.2f \n", dAvAge);


    for (i = 0; i<= (iNumberOfLines-1); i++){
        sumTime = sumTime + pStudents[i].Time;
    }
    //dAvTime = sumTime/iNumberOfLines;
    printf("Average Time is = %.2f \n", dAvTime);
}
```

Comment: You want to input `12.24` as an `int`? ??? Two `int`s (`a = 12; b = 24;`)???

Comment: Sorry what numbers are you talking about? I dont have the value 12.24 anywhere. I just want to add all ages then devide by the number of people and print that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding

```
    double *dAvHeight;
    dAvHeight = malloc(sizeof(dAvHeight));
    double *dAvAge;
    dAvAge = malloc(sizeof(dAvAge));
    double *dAvTime;
    dAvTime = malloc(sizeof(dAvTime));
```

in the main function and removing the int declarations in the start

and by doing what S3gfault suggested

Thanks !

Comment: Allocation sizes are not correct.  `sizeof(dAvHeight)` is the size of a pointer, not a `double`. 
 Use `p = malloc(sizeof *p);`

Answer (score 1):

If you replace:

```
dAvHeight = sumHeight/ iNumberOfLines;
```

with this:

```
*dAvHeight = (double)sumHeight / iNumberOfLines;
```

Than that should do the trick. You would also have to do something similar to the lines you commented out.

The asterisk is to make sure you are writing to the place where the pointer is pointing and the `(double)` is in place because otherwise it would first do the division and then the conversion, which could for exmple lead to:

```
(double)(5 / 2) = (double)2 = 2.0
```

instead of

```
(double)5 / 2 = 5.0 / 2 = 2.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense. However, for some reason nothing is being printed and i cant really see why. If i add another printf line printing "sumHeight" for example then theres no problem

Comment: What happens when you replace it with this `printf("Average Height is = %f \n", dAvHeight);`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same problem, do i maybe need to cast something before calling the dAvHeight?